# Receiving a continuation character Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, syntax

Does anyone know why am I receiving this syntax error?

```
    def softmax(self,x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def encrypt(self,pubkey,scaling_factor=1000):
    if(not self.encrypted):
        self.pubkey = pubkey
        self.scaling_factor = float(scaling_factor)
        self.encrypted_weights = list()

        for weight in model.weights:
            self.encrypted_weights.append(self.pubkey.encrypt(\\ 
            int(min(weight,self.maxweight) * self.scaling_factor)))
        self.encrypted = True            
        self.weights = None

    return self

File "<ipython-input-33-9ca6863eb9a3>", line 11
self.encrypted_weights.append(self.pubkey.encrypt(\\
                                                     ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you forgot to put the keyword `self` before `model.weight`, and import `np` from `numpy`. Try this:

```
import np
def softmax(self,x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def encrypt(self,pubkey,scaling_factor=1000):
    if(not self.encrypted):
        self.pubkey = pubkey
        self.scaling_factor = float(scaling_factor)
        self.encrypted_weights = list()

    for weight in self.model.weights:
        self.encrypted_weights.append(self.pubkey.encrypt(int(min(weight, self.maxweight) * self.scaling_factor)))
    self.encrypted = True            
    self.weights = None

return self
```